# Java - How To Create A Single-Instance Program

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Am developing a certain management system, however i have a problem. Every time i launch the system it keeps showing it's self in the toolbar meaning it runs many times instead of running once.... Is there any way I can create a launcher that checks if an instance of program is already running, if it's running to prevent it from opening another instance.. The image below show what i want to avoid....

[image]

Comment: I usually lock a file when the application opens and release it when the application closes. Not 100% bulletproof but it has always done the job for me.

Comment: |@SirTroll How do you do that ? any code please?